# Why doesn't ejs recognize my views and change the title?

Tags: node.js, ejs, node-modules

I just started using ejs and I am trying to change the title from my "app.js" script. Here is my app.js:

```
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//Listen for requests
app.listen(3000);

//Render different sites
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", {title:"Home"});
})

app.get("/pokemon", (req, res) => {
    res.render("pokemon");
})
```

And here is how I am trying to set the title using ejs in "index.ejs":

`<title> <%= title %> </title>`

Here is my file structure:

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQDD.png)

And my dependencies:

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrGbO.png)

As far as I understand I am using the standard folder name of "views" which should work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure view engline as ejs in file.  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: @Akshay from what you sent me it says "This defaults to the views directory in the application root directory.", which mine is.

Comment: what error your getting...

Comment: @ash I am not getting an error, it just doesn't work. It seems like ejs isn't recognized at all.

Comment: did you install the ejs properly here is the link to give you more info .. https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express

Comment: I just tried answering your new question about Pokemon. Have you already solved it? You have given column as the `flex-direction`. Did you actually try out how it looks when you do it normally before converting it into a component?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Hi Praveen, thank you for trying to help. I changed flex-direction to row as I realized that was a mistake. This has solved some of the issue. Right now I am trying to push the Bulbasaur image down under his name, but I am struggling to do that using flexbox, as it wants to align the items as a row.

Comment: @MongoosePainter Have you got the question up again? I can try answering the solution!  Happy to get an accepted answer.